# What determines which player gets materials?

Tags: spiral-knights

While venturing in the clockworks, especially in a party, sometimes monsters drop materials.  That said, sometimes I will kill a monster all on my own.  But when I go to collect the material dropped, another player on my team collects said material.

How will I know who gets what materials?

Comment: I'm John-The-Green, in game, btw. :)

Comment: I'll make note of that :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [July 30, 2013 update](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Release_Notes_2013-07-30), materials are dropped independent of other players (stuff you see won't be seen by others).

This means you won't have to worry about not getting certain materials, all material drops (you must collect them yourself) are guaranteed to go to you.